# I using Nlog with dotnet-core-2.2 in centos but a problem with log file path setting is appear

Tags: .net-core, nlog, .net-core-2.2

I am running an aspnet core consol program on centos.I have set up nlog.config to Generate log files. All is well in my windows development environment,but when I run it on Centos I can't get logs files using my settings.
My setting:

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="target1" fileName="${currentdir}\logs\${shortdate}-nlog.log" ... />
```

[In centos:(click to show img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJj21.jpg)
It will create a file name "demoBS\logs\2019-06-26-nlog.log" in parent directory.

Thank you and look forward to your help!

Ps: Nlog.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XSD manual extracted from package NLog.Schema: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Schema-->
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogFile="${currentdir}\logs\${shortdate}-internal.log"
      internalLogLevel="Info" >

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="target1" fileName="${currentdir}\logs\${shortdate}-nlog.log"
            layout="${date}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message} ${exception}|${logger}|${all-event-properties}" />
    <target xsi:type="Console" name="target2"
            layout="${date}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message} ${exception}|${logger}|${all-event-properties}" />
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="target2,target1" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Please edit the title to reflect your specific question, if you need to ask multiple questions consider making 2 posts.

Comment: Make sure to use Unix-path instead of Windows-path. Ex `${currentdir}/logs/${shortdate}-nlog.log` (Turn the slashes the other way)

Comment: My problem has been solved. Thank you @Rolf Kristensen

Comment: Great to hear. Have now posted my comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use Unix-path instead of Windows-path. Ex:

- `${currentdir}/logs/${shortdate}-nlog.log`

Turn the slashes the other way

Comment: I am a beginner of using linux , Thank for your help ,My problem has been solved.